# How to get change in font size to show in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

So the code that I currently have is meant for a user to paste text into the ckeditor, and then when they click submit, it will identify certain characters and change their font sizes. This works when the text is shown outside of ckeditor when in a normal textarea, but the changes in font size are not shown inside the ckeditor. How can I get the ckeditor to recognize the change in fonts and font sizes? Here is my code:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/full/ckeditor.js"></script>      
</head>      
<body>         
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); filterTextArea();">  
<div name="space" id="space"> </div>         
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80" >     </textarea>           <br>    
<div id="formbox">  <button action="submit" id = "submit" >WORDIPLY</button>        </div>              
<script>      

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
customConfig: 'www.wordiply.weebly.com/files/theme/ckeditor.js'
});      
</script>      
</body>        
<body>                        
<script>

function filterTextArea(){    
editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;     
var edata = editor.getData(); 

//CHANGE FONT OF CHARACTERS  

editor.setData(data);    
}    

var config = {};  
config.placeholder = 'some value';   
CKEDITOR.replace("myeditor" , config, {
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be looking for the following addon:
http://ckeditor.com/addon/font

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I already have that integrated into the editor

Comment: @CStrick, hmm. and you still cant see the font sizes in-line?  I wonder if there is some configuration that is missing...